# JAVA - Execute a conditional if statement for a null value using getters and setters

Tags: java, if-statement, null, this, getter-setter

I have an issue with returning and replacing the value `null` with something with meaning from another class using getters and setters and would like to know what I have done incorrectly.

Configuration for getters and setters:

```
public class CarClass {

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int yearOfMake;

    public void setMake(String make){
        if (make.isEmpty()){
            this.make = "";
            System.out.println("Error please input value");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            this.make = make; 
        }
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {

        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        if (model.isEmpty()){
            this.model = "";
            System.out.println("Error, you have not entered a valid model");
        } else {
            this.model = model;
        }
    }

    public int getYearOfMake() {
        return yearOfMake;
    }

    public void setYearOfMake(int yearOfMake) {
        if (yearOfMake > 1900)
            this.yearOfMake = yearOfMake;
        else {
            this.yearOfMake = yearOfMake;
            System.out.println("Year of make is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Execution script for above:

```
public class GetterSetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarClassTwo bmw = new CarClassTwo();
        bmw.setMake();
        System.out.println(bmw.getMake());
        CarClass benz = new CarClass();
        benz.setModel("C300");
        System.out.println(benz.getModel());
        benz.setYearOfMake(1999);
        System.out.println(benz.getYearOfMake());
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!");
        benz.setModel("C300");
        System.out.println(benz.getModel());
        benz.setYearOfMake(1800);
        System.out.println(benz.getYearOfMake());
        System.out.println(bmw.getMake());
        System.out.println(bmw.getModel());
    }
}
```

Any assistance into understand what I have done incorrectly would be most appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? A NullPointerException?

Comment: Nowhere in this code are you checking if something is null. You call `isEmpty()` in a couple of places, but that will throw an exception if the variable is null. If you want to check if (e.g.) `make` is null, you should write `if (make==null)...`

Comment: But also you can't call `setMake()` without argument if the `setMake` method requires an argument. Not passing an argument isn't the same as that argument being null.

Comment: ahh I think I understood what you said.

What I wanted to do is check if the default variable is null, just display an error message saying "You have to enter something"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the following code is executed:

```
CarClassTwo bmw = new CarClassTwo();
bmw.setMake();
```

at that time the values of

```
private String make;
private String model;
```

are initialized to null by default.

So when `bmw.setMake();` is executed, it executes `if (make.isEmpty()){`

which is something like null.isEmpty() --> which will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: I wanted to produce an error message, if my default value were empty or in this instance 'null'

Comment: @ras there aren't any defaults defined as per your code. If you want to assign defaults, then assign them at the beginning itself. Like below:
```
private String make = "default_make";
private String model = "default_model";
private int yearOfMake = "0";
```